# Как импортировать модуль, импортирующий модуль

Tags: python, python-import

В одной папке лежат три py-файла:

```
main.py
module.py
submodule.py
```

Содержимое файла `submodule.py`:

```
import random    

def func():
    x = random.randint(1, 100)
    return x
```

Содержимое файла `module.py`:

```
from submodule import func

data = [
    ('number', func()),
    ('param', 'key'),
]
```

Содержимое файла `main.py`

```
from module import data

while True:
    response = requests.post(url='http://site.com', data=data)
```

При запуске файла `main.py`, вывод следующий:

```
[('number', 8), ('param', 'key')]
[('number', 8), ('param', 'key')]
[('number', 8), ('param', 'key')]
[('number', 8), ('param', 'key')]
[('number', 8), ('param', 'key')]
[('number', 8), ('param', 'key')]
[('number', 8), ('param', 'key')]
[('number', 8), ('param', 'key')]
```

Уважаемые знатоки. Как мне добиться исполнения функции `func()` при каждом проходе цикла while, не перенося функцию в другой модуль?

Comment: по-нормальному, сделай `data` функцией, а не объектом... если нужно чтобы он был именно объектом, то можно сделать его мимикрирующим под список (возможно есть нечто готовое)... возможны и другие варианты, в зависимости от того какие запросы у requests.post() к параметрам...

Comment: какая связь между заголовком и телом вопроса? У вас вопрос фактически: "как проинициализировать переменную из другого модуля при каждом  проходе цикла". (ответ: замените `data = [func()]` на `get_data = lambda: [func()]` и затем в цикле: `data=get_data()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас в списке `data` фиксируется одно значение из `func` и после этого файл `module` не будет каждый раз обращаться к `submodule`. Попробуйте так:

> Пакет submodule:

```
def func(numb):
   x = numb
   return x
```

> Пакет module:

```
from submodule import func
import random
def data_func():
    data = [
        ('number', func(random.randint(0,100))),
        ('param', 'key')]
    return data
```

> main

```
import module as mod
while True:
    print(mod.data_func())
```

Comment: не подходит. тот же вывод

Comment: @MIKS понял что вы имели ввиду, поправил ответ, теперь вроде работает